# Tongue exercises helping English

Tags: pronunciation

I have a question about pronunciation. I've been studying English practically for my whole life, but for some reason I have such a hard time pronouncing the FLAP T.

I do know how to make it perfectly, but whenever I try to pronounce it it sounds really forced and whenever I try to talk fast like If i want to say 'It was such a pretty day" or Whenever the 'PRETTY' word comes up I get so stucked! Don't even get me started on pronouncing words like "turtle, murder, or saying "ORDER TO".

I used to practice English like crazy when I was a kid and a teenager and even in adulthood,  making the flap T, would be extremely easy, been practicing 3 hours daily for over 5 months with words like "murder, turtle and listening to native speakers saying it and repeating it with them". Still, CAN'T pronounce it properly and fluently. Why? Do I need to focus on "tongue exercises"? JAW exercises too? I don't know, This sound is giving me such a hard time, and sometimes I just feel like givin' up on English.

Comment: You'll probably get more traction for this question over on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Try "prit-ti" ,"tur-tul", 'mur-der", etc. There is no good reason to speak English with any great speed. Slow down. Many English speakers prefer words to come distinctly and not as if there were a race to see how many words per minute can be thrown out.

Comment: @Carlos Fernandez... I actually use the pronunciations I suggested at times.  Another way I say "pretty" is "pur-di". Also "tur-dul". The real issue IS getting "stuck". Don't try to say something you cannot say.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I do think the next. If you can't do something, you just dont have to give up. I had trouble with the American r sound but never give up and managed to say it. But thanks for your reply!!

Comment: I’m guessing by your name that your first language is either Spanish or Portuguese. If so, good news: the flapped t in English is phonetically /ɾ/, almost exactly like a single, non-initial r in both those languages. Apart from some slight differences in vowel quality (and the aspiration in the initial consonant), AmE _Betty_ and Spanish _peri_ sound almost exactly the same.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek, I'll suggest that you need to search the web for a list of "tongue-twisters" to practice.

Comment: Don't worry about it Carlos, I'm British and I have difficulty _hearing_ the differences between some of the examples I've found online of the pronunciation of a 'd' and a 'flapped t', let alone reproducing the difference! To me the word 'letter' pronounced by an American using a 'flapped t' sounds just like 'ledder', I suspect that if I told an American I'd had a 'ledder' from someone it would sound odd to him but, as I said I can't hear the difference between an American 'd' and a 'flapped t'. Don't let such a minor point spoil your study of the English language.

Comment: @Bold I'm American, been here since birth. I can just barely hear the difference between the two sounds, even though I unconsciously produce it. When I studied it in linguistics class, the professor had to alternate "ladder" and "latter" multiple times before I could detect it. I think the words are distinguished mostly by context and not by sound.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm beginning to think that it's a manufactured distinction invented to make life unnecessarily difficult for people learing English as second or subsequent language. Hope Carlos is reading this!

Comment: @Bold Thinking about it more, "fatter" definitely doesn't sound like "fadder." In any case I always *feel* like I'm saying the t. I *could* substitute it with a full t sound. But it would sound so.... I don't know, British!

Comment: @MattSamuel Then there's the Tony Curtis line "Yonder lies the castle of my fodder" in [The Prince Who Was Thief](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/life-with-fodder/). I get the impression that not even Americans thought that "fodder" sounded like "father"

Comment: @Bold Couldn't possibly. "Father" has the "th" sound, which would never sound like d, I don't think. I wouldn't think the consonant in father is different between British and American English.

Comment: @MattSamuel That's true, but its always worth having a go at Tony Curtis!

Comment: You don't strictly have to follow American pronunciation when speaking English. Even if you use a hard t, people would still understand you are saying. Of course, this doesn't mean that I'm discouraging you to do so.